# How to connect to PostgreSQL cluster on DigitalOcean from CircleCI?

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean, circleci, circleci-workflows

I have a Kubernetes cluster setup on DigitalOcean and a separate database Postgres instance there. In database cluster settings there is a list of limited IP addresses that have an access to that database cluster (looks like a great idea).

I have a build and deploy proccess setup with CircleCI and at the end of that process, after deploying a container to K8s cluster, I need to run database migration. The problem is that I don't know CircleCI agent IP address and can not allow it in DO settings. Does anybody know how we can access DigitalOcean Postgres cluster from within CircleCI steps?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately when you use a distributed service like that that you don't manage, I would be very cautious about using the restricted IP approach. (Really you have three services you don't manage - Postgres, Kubernetes, and CircleCI.) I feel as if DigitalOcean has provided a really excellent security option for internal networking, since it can track changes in droplet IP, etc.

But when you are deploying on another service, especially if this is for production, and even if the part of your solution you're deploying is deployed (partially) on DigitalOcean infrastructure, I'd be very concerned that CircleCI will change IP dynamically. DO has no way of knowing when this happens, as unlike Postgres and Kubernetes, they don't manage it even if they do host part of it

Essentially I have to advise you to either get an assurance of a static IP from your CircleCI vendor/provider, or disable the IP limitation on Postgres.